# Are there any apocryphal writings to suggest that Jesus used a cart to travel long distances?

Tags: life-of-jesus, denomination-survey, apocrypha

Jesus traveled extensively   during the period his Ministry. Gospels depict him travelling on foot and by boat, the former  covering the total distance of approximately 3000 miles. Some  individual round trips would be of  100 miles each( Matt. 16:13 and Mark 8:27). One does not, however, come across in the Gospels,  any account of Jesus traveling on a cart pulled  by animals say, bullock. Nor does one get to see images showing Jesus taking such a ride. My question therefore,  is: Are there any apocryphal writings to suggest that Jesus used a cart to travel long distances, during his public life .   Inputs from any denomination are welcome.